# Detecting unused makefile command line arguments

Tags: makefile, command-line-arguments

### Background

If I have a makefile with an optional argument, I normally will use:

```
make target
```

but sometimes (if I think there might be a problem with the assembler optimisations) I want to pass an extra command line argument, e.g.

```
make target VERIFY_ASSEMBLY_OPTIMISATIONS=1
```

### Problem

Sometimes I may have a typo in the command line argument, e.g.

```
make target VERIFY_ASSEMBLY_OPTIMIZATIONS=1
```

and this can cause me to waste a lot of time as the wrong thing has been built.

### Question

Is there a simple way of verifying Makefile command line arguments?

In other words, I want the Makefile to instantly raise an error if an unrecognized command line argument has been used.

### What I've tried

I've tried the following code to detect unexpected variables:

```
ALLOWED_VARS := foo bar
$(foreach v,                                   \
  $(filter-out $(ALLOWED_VARS),$(.VARIABLES)), \
  $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

Unfortunately, this seems to detect lots of extra variables (such as LANG, TERM, LEX) that I did not specify on the command line.

Comment: How do you define _unrecognized command line arguments_?  The above is just defining a variable.  How is make going to know that it's not the right variable?

Comment: @MadScientist I am quite happy to put code in my Makefile to say which variables are allowed.  In most languages I can get a list of command line arguments (e.g. in argv) and can check each one in turn that it is something I allow, I just don't know how to do this within a Makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undocumented variable that contains all the command line variable assignments, `-*-command-variables-*-` (yes, that's the actual name of the variable).

So if you have this makefile:

```
all:
        @echo '$(-*-command-variables-*-)'
```

and you run `make`, it will print nothing.  If you run `make FOO=bar BIZ=baz`, it will print `FOO=bar BIZ=baz`.  This is not 100% reliable because this is an undocumented variable and so it's conceivable that someday it may change, and it's slightly problematic because it quotes whitespace, so `make FOO='foo bar'` with the above makefile will print `FOO=foo\ bar`.  But it's probably good enough.

If you wanted it to be bulletproof the only option I can suggest is looping through the `$(.VARIABLES)` value, which contains a list of variables that have been defined, passing each to the `$(origin ...)` function and looking for `command line` as the value.  Something like this:

```
CMDVARS := $(strip $(foreach V,$(.VARIABLES),$(if $(findstring command,$(origin $V)),$V)))
```

Comment: Just being curious: if its undocumented, how did you find that? Or did you dig into the make source? Anyway, very useful.

Comment: Oh, I didn't check your website, seems that you are actually deeply involved into make ;-) !

Comment: @MadScientist - very useful - alas you bulletproof equivalent could be improved as
$(info COMMAND_LINE_VARIABLES: $(strip $(foreach V,$(.VARIABLES),$(if $(findstring command,$(origin $V)),${V}=$(value ${V})))))

Comment: That's an improvement IFF the user wants to see that list printed out every time.  That may be the case if debugging this variable but doubtful it's wanted after that.

Comment: @malcook THANKS A LOT! i almost lost hope finding answer to my question :)

Comment: alas `-*-command-variables-*-` appears deprecated in gnu Make v. 4.4.

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes in the use or behavior of this variable in GNU Make 4.4 (or 4.4.1).

Comment: Apologies - I wrote incorrectly in haste.